# TensorFlow 2.0: How to update tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow 1.x, to update a tensor, I would use `tf.scatter_update`, to only update the relevant part of the tensor.

How can we do the same thing in TF 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones((2, 2)), dtype=tf.float32)
indices = tf.constant([[0, 0]])
updates = tf.constant([0.0])

tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates).numpy()
# array([[0., 1.],
#        [1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Actually this is not doing what I need, it creates a new object. Is there any way to use a reference to the same object? If I want to update some memory variables, such as a replay buffer, tensorflow returns an error: "An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. "

Comment: I found the answer to my own question: tensor.assign(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(....  works.

Comment: @gpernelle In your question you actually wanted to update a variable and not a tensor object (that is what tf.scatter_update did in 1.x). The answer by Vlad is thus correct in updating tensors. Your answer is correct for updating Variables, although I don't know why this functionality disappeared in 2.x.